# Ellipse Not Appearing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ellipse

When I try to get an Ellipse it does not show. I set the colour, size, and location.

Here is my current code:

```
public static Ellipse MainSnake = new Ellipse();

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    MainSnake.Height = 10;
    MainSnake.Width = 10;
    MainSnake.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
    Canvas.SetLeft(MainSnake, 250);
    Canvas.SetTop(MainSnake, 150);
}
```

When I click the button all that appears is the background.

[image: what I am experiencing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ellipse is a GUI object and should thus be being generated at runtime, you also need to add it to the canvas's Children collection:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    Ellipse MainSnake = new Ellipse();
    MainSnake.Height = 10;
    MainSnake.Width = 10;
    MainSnake.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
    Canvas.SetLeft(MainSnake, 250);
    Canvas.SetTop(MainSnake, 150);

    theCanvas.Children.Add(MainSnake);
}
```

Comment: Just about to say the same thing. +1